# What are elementary particles according to Loop Quantum Gravity?

Tags: elementary-particles, loop-quantum-gravity

Are elementary particles still excitations of quantum fields in LQG?

Comment: Loop quantum gravity, I believe, is matter free, unlike string theory it doesn't try to predict the standard model from first principles. Curiously, it's about as good at predicting the standard model as string theory is. :-)

Comment: c'mon, show a bit of research effort. What do you know about LQG (does it even *have* "quantum fields"?)? What do you mean by "excitation"? (A particle is a certain state in the asymptotic Fock space of a QFT, to call that an "excitation" is vague and not really helpful to compare it wiht other theories)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: It might be helpful to get an idea of the purpose and history of loop quantum gravity by starting with this link:  http://igpg.gravity.psu.edu/people/Ashtekar/articles/rovelli03.pdf.

Comment: @ACuriousMind *"This question was blocked on physics stack exchange because they’re being overly dismissive. This question is usually not adequately answered in popular explanations of LQG, nor on the wikipedia page, so I think it deserves an answer somewhere!"* Link: https://www.quora.com/What-are-elementary-particles-according-to-Loop-Quantum-Gravity . And, well, check that answer too, what the question got there. Maybe it would seem quite well also on the PSE?